# How do I get around tables that need to be sorted in two groups of four while using will_paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, will-paginate

I'm using `will_paginate` to paginate my items eight at a time.

I want to organize them in a table with two rows and four columns while still maintaining pagination. How can I do this?

So far I have:

```
<%= will_paginate @items, :page_links => false %>
<table id="item_table">
    <tr>
    <% for item in @items %>
        <td>Test</td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But I need to change this somehow that I can have `@items` be a temporary array of every four items, instead of eight. Here's the ideal output:

```
<-- 1 2 ... 5 6 -->
Test Test Test Test
Test Test Test Test
```

Where obviously the top links lead to the next eight items. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**
[each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) is an enumerable itself so there is not need to create an array before calling each on it, I reduced the code by a line
    <% @item.each_slice(4) do |item_new| %>
      
        <% item_new.each do |item|%>
          <%= item.name %>
        <% end %>
      
    <% end %>

The code is just a snippet from one of my app, implementing almost the same thing you are trying to achieve, I hope it does help, don't forget to include the will_paginate and complete the table. This is just some logic you would require.

Comment: Really elegant. At first I was trying to do something with shift, but it was just too sloppy.

Comment: Great answer.. Very nice and succinct

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with pagination. The question is related to views. You can use CSS to control your views!

Still, if you prefer to generate a 2x4 grid from code, try this:

```
<table id="item_table">
  <% @items.each_with_index |v,i| %>
      <%if i%4 == 0 %>
        <tr>
      <%end%> 
      <td>Test</td>
      <%if i%4 == 0 and i > 0%>
     </tr>
    <%end%> 
  <% end %>
</table>
```

You can refactor it easily to remove code repetition.

Comment: Can you explain why are there nested tr's?

Comment: first tr is start tag second one is end tag.

Comment: Nice answer.. But accepted answer is best.. Good effort Naveed

Answer (score 0):

view:

```
<%= will_paginate @items %>
<table id="item_table">
 <tr>
  <% for item in @items[0..3] %>
   <td><%= item.name %></td>
  <% end %>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <% for item in @items[4..7] %>
   <td><%= item.name %></td>
  <% end %>
 </tr>
</table>
```

controller:

```
@items = Item.paginate :per_page => 8, :page => params[:page]
```

This is a little dirty, there's probably a better way to split the rows, but this is quick.
Also, this is the kind of thing i'd normally use divs for, so then you can just let them wrap round freely.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this actually but will_paginate breaks down. I'm not sure if it's something having to do with the fact that this seems to limit you to the first 8 items (I think this should only give you items 0..3 and 4..7 repeatedly, no?)

Comment: it would give 0..3 (first 4) and 4..7 (second 4) for the returned results. And when you click page 2 the results will be 9-16, but that's still an array of 8 items, see? so we still want 4 + 4. "will_paginate breaks down" can you post the error?

Comment: There's no "error" or exception, per se. What happens is that when I try to click the next link, nothing happens.